# How to pass Google/sheetsAPI data to website?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, google-api, aws-lambda

Sooooo,
I want to get data from a google sheet to a website which appends the passed data dynamically to the website so the amount of itme's on the website is equal to the amount of rows. I pretty much got everything done separately but I just cant seem to figure out how to combine them. 
I set up a node.js project which uses my Api key to retrieve the data, manipulate and push it into an array.

also maybe there's a more efficient way to push the data but i couldn't figure anything else out but  saving it to a file and then reading it back. I then pumped that into a AWS api gateway+Lambda funtion which didn't really work because I couldn't get Lambda to require google/api but i think i could sort that out. 
I also already did all the HTML / JS on the website to push the data to the page I just cant seem to figure out how to get the data from my AWS-http-link into my website. No matter if I use async or promise or none of both It just can't get the data.

'ISSUES: using google/api inside Lambda, getting data from Api to array, maybe diffrent way to get the data from google api'

Thank you in advance!

AWS-link:  https://po7bu16g2i.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/live/celldata

```
//JS code on website

var receivearray =[];

function createEntry(data){
  for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    var outdt = document.createElement('div');
      outdt.className='outwrap';

        var pers_name = document.createElement('div');
            pers_name.className='name';
              var pers_name_txt= document.createElement('h3');
                pers_name_txt.className='name_head';
                  pers_name_txt.innerHTML=data[i][0];

              outdt.append(pers_name);
              pers_name.append(pers_name_txt);  


        for(k=1;k<data[i].length;k++){
          var top =document.createElement('div');
            top.className='text_wrap';
              var q = document.createElement('p');
                  q.className='frage';
                  q.innerHTML=data[i][k][0];
              var a= document.createElement('p');
                  a.innerHTML=data[i][k][1];
        outdt.append(top);
        top.append(q,a);    
        }
  document.body.appendChild(outdt);
  }
};
createEntry(receivearray);
```

```
//Node.js Code

//requirements 
var GoogleSpreadsheet = require('google-spreadsheet');
var crds = require('./credt.json');
const fs = require('fs');
//updates the data-tfile
function update(sheetid){
  //google api shapens                
  var doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet(sheetid);

  doc.useServiceAccountAuth(crds, 
    function (err) {

      doc.getRows(1,
        function (err, rows) {
          //saves all retrieved data into textfile 
          fs.writeFile('ting.txt', JSON.stringify(rows), 
            function (err) {
              //checks if file was saved succesfully
              if (err) throw err;
              console.log('updated')
            }
          )
        }
      )
    }
  )
}
function prepdata(){
  //define variables
  var text = fs.readFileSync("ting.txt", "utf8");
  var findata =[];
  var hold=[];
  //singleout all row-elements
  for(x=0;x<text.length;x++){
    if(text.slice(x,x+7)=='"name":'){

      hold.push(text.slice(x+7,x+120));
    }
  }
  //split data by , into sets
  for(x=0;x<hold.length;x++){

    findata.push(hold[x].split(','));
  }
  //push sets into arrays
  for (var k = 0; k < findata.length; k++){
    for (var i = 0; i < findata[k].length; i++){
      findata[k][i] = findata[k][i].replace(/"/g, " ");
      findata[k][i] = findata[k][i].split(':');
    }
  }
  return findata;
}
update("1W6tVuj0krrwI7PyTRJha2ZOX72kGGfFAI8eqXOirWHo");
console.log(prepdata());
```